# Can't add DNN Hovering Module to page in DNN9

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I cannot drag and drop my module on a page in DNN 9. The module works, but I add it to a page. Parts of the module is sticking out on the block that hovers over the panes you can drop the module onto.

[image]

Comment: Does your SKIN have a popup layout in it? You might try changing the page skin to a default skin from DNN and then add the module?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to work with any other Skin. I discovered that I have a JQuery Migration 1.4.1 JavaScript Library installed. If I uninstall the module, it works. I currently get 3 errors in the console. Cannot set property 'selector' of undefined at new JQuery.fn.init when I leave the Library installed.